# Convert JSON to plain java string

Tags: java, android, json

Is there a way to convert a json string into proper java string where it will escape all the quote characters like `{\"hello\":\"world\"}`

I am using android's `json` library with is based on `org.json`.

Thanks

Comment: `JSONObject.getString();`?

Comment: a jave string does not escape anything. it is only escaped in the source code. eclipse does the escaping for you if you ask nicely.

Comment: JSONObject.getString() doesntv escape the quotes. i have to do it manually myself

Answer (score 2):

[Bigflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182436/bigflow) already answered it in comment, just adding part to escape all `"`

```
String obj = JSONObject.getString().replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: I thought `.replace("\"", "\\\"");` isn't even needed. (I don't use the replace code, and seems to work fine at mine) but still +1

Comment: it needs it. it doesnt excape the characters

Comment: @Bigflow: havent used from a long time. Will be great if any of you try it and let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to create a `String` object from an existing `JSONObject` you can just call the `toString()` on it.
if it's a `String` that's formatted as JSON and you want to get the unescaped version of it, try this:

```
public String getString(String json){
    String value = "";
    try {
       value = new JSONObject(json).toString();
    } catch (JSONEcxeption e) {
       value = DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }
    return value;
}
```